# Solr/Lucene - equivalent of LIKE '%foo%' with scoring

Tags: solr, lucene

What's the best way in Solr/Lucene to index a text column to behave like a SQL `LIKE '%foo%` where the best matches come first?  "Best" in my case means exact matches first, then fewer extra characters before more extra.  For example

search for "1234" should return

- 1234
- 12345 (one extra char)
- 01234
- 123456 (two extra chars)
- 001234567890
- etc.

What I've tried so far and doesn't quite work (column mapped as `text_en_splitting`)

- search for `1234` -> only exact matches
- search for `*1234*` -> finds everything but doesn't score exact matches higher
- search for `1234~` -> will match 12345 but doesn't score exact matches higher. Will NOT match longer strings like "001234567890".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To score exact matches higher you might need to search in your field that will provide all matches and the second one what will produce only exact matches (with some boost).

To avoid using asterisks (they are slowing search down) in query you could use [NGramFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramFilterFactory.html) in your schema.

Keeping that in mind your query might look like that:

```
q=1234&qf=ngram_text_field,simple_text_field^2&defType=edismax
```

More info about [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax)

Comment: OK - do you have any idea if ngram searches are scored as well?

Comment: I can't see the reason why they would not be. They're producing regular tokens and that should be enough for Solr/Lucene. My advice is to use ngram only during indexing, and just skip it for query time in field definition

Comment: what i mean is, is Lucene smart enough to rank "better" matches higher?  In other words, if I search on 1234, both 01234 and 001234 would match, because they both contain the ngram '1234'.  But I would want 01234 to have a higher score than 001234.

Comment: If you would not omnit norms (omitNorms="false"), field with 01234 will have higher score due to length normalization, however that also depends length of the whole field. Simplification: If field would any contain 01234 it will be scored higher then field with 001234 because the second one would have more tokens (produced by ngram) than the first one: http://www.lucenetutorial.com/advanced-topics/scoring.html (lengthNorm)